# Query won't insert username into database

Tags: php, mysql

So I've got this query:

```
mysql_query(
    "INSERT INTO  wall_post (post,username,userip,date_created)
    VALUES(
        '".checkValues($_REQUEST['value'])."',
        '".$_SESSION['user']."',
        '".$userip."',
        '".strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s"))."'
    )"
);
```

and I also tried to make the query this way:

```
mysql_query(
    "INSERT INTO wall_post (post,username,userip,date_created)
    VALUES(
            '".checkValues($_REQUEST['value'])."',
            $_SESSION['user'],
            '".$userip."',
            '".strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s"))."'
           )"
);
```

I don't see any error message from the database when the insert fails.

It won't insert the username into the database but when I echo `$_SESSION['user']` it would still show me its content, please I would appreciate some help.

The table structure is:

```
CREATE TABLE wall_post (
    p_id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
    username varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    post varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    image varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    date_created int(11) NOT NULL,
    userip varchar(200) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (p_id)
)
```

The value which contains $_SESSION['user'] is theil, it doesn't have any special character, but if I replace $_SESSION['user'] with a string like $user = "test"; it will insert the value "test" into the database

Comment: Username hace a single quote in it by any chance? Also, look in to use ADO, not raw inserts (always want to sanitize).

Comment: Need table structure.  Need error message.  Need checkValues function.  Sometimes the questions here blow my mind....

Comment: Doesn't show any error message, the username is theil so it doesn't have single quote, table structure is this one:
CREATE TABLE `wall_post` (
  `p_id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `username` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `post` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `image` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `date_created` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `userip` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`p_id`)
)

Comment: @rockerest, no need to be jerk. Some people are new.  Anyway, make a variable contaiing the sql query and echo it and post it here.  You may have empty values.

Comment: @Trevor, here's the echo of the query
INSERT INTO wall_post (post,username,userip,date_created) VALUES('','theil','127.0.0.1','1309975742')

Comment: `checkValues($_REQUEST['value'])` is empty. it probably shouldn't be. Also, try adding `mysql_error()` to your query: `mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());`

Comment: @Trevor it's not about being new.  This is the equivalent of going to McDonald's and saying "I'm hungry."  They would ask you: "What do you want, you have to give me a little to go on."  It's common decency.  If you want help, provide as much info as you possibly can so the people you are asking to **help you for free** can help you.  Honestly, it's kind of rude to expect help but provide nothing but the bare minimum of initial effort.

Comment: @rockerest I agree that there should be effort, but you don't have to be "rude" back to the guy. Help the guy debug or learn how to post here.

Comment: As you can see by your sql query, there is nothing within the Request key. Are you using the correct key?

Answer (score 2):

[`mysql_query`](https://www.php.net/mysql_query) for insert statements either returns True on success or False on error. You have to check the return value if it was successful, and if it wasn't successful get the error via `mysql_error`:

```
$result = mysql_query($sql);
if (!$result) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

It should be easy to fix from there.

Comment: It doesn't show any error after dong what you said, it is inserting everything except the username, but when I try to inset it this way:
$result = mysql_query(
    "INSERT INTO  wall_post (post,username,userip,date_created)
    VALUES(
        '".checkValues($_REQUEST['value'])."',
        '"USERNAME"',
        '".$userip."',
        '".strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s"))."'
    )"
);

it appears in the database without problem.

Answer (score 2):

The image column is set to NOT NULL, but you are not inserting anything into it. I suspect removing the NOT NULL clause, or setting a default value for the column might fix your problem.

Additional tip. use MYSQLS NOW() for the date. Just let the database handle that bit :)

Comment: It did not solve the problem, I'm guessing it has something to do with the string $_SESSION['user'] is passing since whenever I replace it with a variable containing a string, it would post the string to the database.

Comment: Sounds like you already have a DEFAULT value set for that column then :) Which makes the NOT NULL a bit redundant :)

Comment: have you tried echoing the data of $_SESSION['user'] , what is the exact string you receive?

Comment: theil just that, my user name.

Comment: sounds strange, I still cant wrap my head around your database allows you to insert NULL values into a NOT NULL column (if your CREATE TABLE syntax reflects the table in the database, it really shouldn't) and that mysql_error() doesnt report anything. Heres a suggestion, create the query string as a variable $query = "INSERT bla bla" , echo variable, run mysql_query($variable). Execute the echoed $query directly in mysql. If it runs, and mysql_query doesnt run, you have some sort of driver issue.

Answer (score 1):

just check what the value is and make sure there are no special characters in there.

You can also try "'.mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['user']).'"

the problem might be special characters.

From all the comments try this

$name = isset($_REQUEST['user']) ? $_REQUEST['user'] : '';

mysql_query('INSERT INTO wall_post (post,username,userip,date_created) VALUES("'..checkValues($_REQUEST['value']).'",
 "'.$name.'","'$ipAddress'","'.$timestamp.'")');

Comment: The value is theil so I assume there is not any special character, I also tried mysql_real_escape_string and didn't work either.

Comment: echo out that query and paste it here please, if you do not mind

Comment: You also do not need to do a php date() function. instead you can just do UTC_TIMESTAMP() as part of your query string

Comment: Also put the $_SESSION['user'] in quotes. it will never work unquoted unless its an integer

Comment: it is quoted and here's the echo it returned:
 INSERT INTO wall_post (post,username,userip,date_created) VALUES('','theil','127.0.0.1','1309975742')

Comment: it seems to be working directly under my sql db on my localhost. i really do not understand what the problem could be

Comment: I have more than an hour trying to solve this but I can't see what's wrong with it. =/

Comment: run the query that you echoed directly from php my admin or something and see if it inserts then

Comment: it would give me an error because it doesn't know what's the value of $_SESSION['user'].

Comment: i understand that but the one that you echo out onto the screen take that and run it directly. also "$_SESSION['usuario']", isnt that supposed to be $_SESSION['user'] or was that a typo

Comment: The weird thing is that if I pass a string in the query, it would insert it without problem, but whenever I try passing the value of the user name returned via GET it won't, I also tried typecasting and didn't work either.

Comment: Was a typo, my bad but it's still the same.

Comment: can you maybe send me that snipped of code or post it where you are get executing the query?

Comment: try this $_SESSION['user'] = isset($_SESSION['user']) ? $_SESSION['user'] : 'empty'; just before the query and see whats in the table. if it displays empty then you know the session var is not set

Comment: The problem is that most of it is in spanish.

Comment: it inserted the value empty, so it means it is not set, right?

Comment: yes that means your session var is not set or it gets overwritten

Comment: check your code. also var_dump($_SESSION) and see whats in the session but thats where your problem is

Comment: if I do put this:
$usuario = $_GET['user'];
$name = isset($usuario) ? $usuario : 'empty';
it would still put it to null, and the value in get is this
profile.php?request=wall&user=theil

Comment: var_dump shows me this in the username:

  'user' => string 'theil' (length=5)

Comment: why are you looking for a session var when you have a get var? also use the $name var in you query instead of the $_SESSION['user'] because you are assigning a value to name. also better to do a $_REQUEST than $_GET or $_POST unless you are sure its either one

Comment: Well I also tried with $name, didn't work either, and well let me check out if it would work with $_REQUEST

Comment: i modified my answer check it try something in the lines of that and let me know

Comment: Didn't work either, this is so weird, so that tells me that it is not set, but if I echo $name after the query it shows its value which would be theil without the line of code you posted.

Answer (score 1):

From one of your comments above, I learnt that if you echo your query, it shows as

```
INSERT INTO wall_post (post,username,userip,date_created) 
VALUES('','theil','127.0.0.1','1309975742')
```

Did you do this echo just before the statement where you run the query? If not, I'd request you to please do the echo just before the call, like this:

```
echo "INSERT INTO  wall_post (post,username,userip,date_created) VALUES(
    '".checkValues($_REQUEST['value'])."',
    '".$_SESSION['user']."',
    '".$userip."',
    '".strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s"))."')"; 
mysql_query("INSERT INTO  wall_post (post,username,userip,date_created) VALUES(
    '".checkValues($_REQUEST['value'])."',
    '".$_SESSION['user']."',
    '".$userip."',
    '".strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s"))."')"
);
```

Your query seems to be absolute fine and should run fine. The only reason why username might not be saving into the database is that `$_SESSION['user'] is empty or does not exist.

Did you try running this echoed query - `INSERT INTO wall_post (post, username, userip, date_created) VALUES('', 'theil', '127.0.0.1', '1309975742')` - directly into MySQL, either on the prompt or any other client that you might be using?

Comment: I echoed it after the query and that was the result I got, if I put the query into MySQL it would insert those values flawlessly, the problems seems to be in $_SESSION['user']; which I got from GET but I even tried this to pass $name in the query: $name = isset($_REQUEST['usuario']) ? $_REQUEST['usuario'] : ' '; did not work either, it is like it isn't set yet in the echo it shows the value.

Comment: @Theil: If the problem is in $_SESSION['user'] that it might be empty or not set when the query is run, why is it showing in the echo? It must not show in the echoed query either. Are you 100% sure that $_SESSION['user'] is existing and non-empty at the time the query is running? Can you do a `print_r($_SESSION)` just before you call mysql_query() and see what it outputs?